# Return address in stack before function call: To which segment points the return address?

Tags: c, return, buffer-overflow, exploit

I am currently learning on buffer overflow attacks. 
I understand that the idea is to overwrite the return address.

The return address points to the statement that follows the function call. What I am wondering: Does this pointer point to the text segment of the program? Or does it point to the heap or something else?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This is highly platform-specific. The return address is not even necessarily on the stack.

Comment: @EugeneSh. In fact most architectures other than x86(_64) use a link register

Comment: @GovindParmar Indeed (not sure about "most" though). But apparently they still use stack for nested calls.

Comment: The purpose of a "buffer overflow" is not to "overwrite the return address.". that is the purpose of a _buffer overflow exploit_; otherwise the overflow itself is simply a run-time error.

Comment: What is meant by program here? The text segment? I am regarding to this figure: https://www.google.com/search?q=tanenbaum+bufferoverflow&rlz=1C5CHFA_enDE706DE706&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1tOKnoargAhUD26QKHS0dBDsQ_AUIESgE&biw=1440&bih=772#imgrc=sE2RndYOJ4vRVM:

Comment: @user235306 What part of that diagram do you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're referring to return addresses on the stack, I'm going to assume that you're on the ubiquitous x86_64.  You can examine this yourself by replacing the `call` instruction with its equivalent `push`, `jmp`, and label (assuming `myfn` is a leaf routine):

```
push offset RA1
jmp _myfn
RA1:
; Remainder of instructions in the calling code...
```

When I actually assemble this I get the following code:

```
00401004: 68 0B 10 40 00     push        40100Bh ; RA1
00401009: EB F5              jmp         00401000 ; myfn
0040100B: 33 C0              xor         eax,eax ; next instruction
```

Now, 00400000 is the default base address for executables on the MS Windows PE format, and for this particular executable of mine, it says that the `.text` (i.e. code) section runs from 00401000 to 0040100D, so yes, the return address in `[esp]` when `myfn` is called indeed points within the `.text` segment.

Where else did you think it might point? The return address has to be to the address of the instruction immediately after the `call` instruction, which, like all other code, goes in the `.text` segment.